# Order on SUM with left outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails app and I am using a scope for a sort like this:

```
group('"expenditures"."id"').order('SUM("expenditure_items"."amount") ' +  direction)
```

There is an outer_left_join(:expenditure_items) before this.  The issue is that when there are no expenditure_items the SUM sorts the other non zero sum items first.  It looks like this:

- SUM
- $100
- $200
- $300
- $0
- $0
- $0

I want the $0 items first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE`:

```
group('"expenditures"."id"').order('COALESCE(SUM("expenditure_items"."amount"),0) '+ direction)
```

or [`NULLS FIRST/LAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) clause:

```
SUM("expenditure_items"."amount")  NULLS FIRST
```